# where is libxml2.dylib located for iOS?

Tags: ios, ios5, libxml2

I cant locate it in the Developer folder in xcode 4 with the iOS 5 sdk, and have not been able to find one by a spotlight search or by looking online.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS5.0.sdk/usr/lib`

A little shell poking usually does the trick:

```
$ find /Developer -name "libxml*.dylib"
```

Answer (score 1):

I found some kind of way found

1. Once in the file selection window do "CMD"+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> (Go to folder) and type /usr/lib/
2. From /usr/lib you can see : libz.dylib and libxml2.dylib more lib

Also IN TERMINAL we can find the lib by using this command

**find / -name libxml2.dylib**

All the best !!!

Answer (score 0):

use `find . -name "libxml2.dylib"` next time.

first match is:

/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS5.0.sdk/usr/lib/libxml2.dylib